# View Reference in Controller EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I am not able to get combobox value in a controller. The getter method of combobox view returns

```
function i(){
    return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)||null
}
```

instead of view object instance. If I use

```
var combo=this.getColumnTypeComboView().create()
```

then I don't get selected value of the combobox `combo.getValue()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get view reference in a controller simply use [getView()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-getView) method from the Controller class. To create a connection between view and a controller make sure that you follow MVC aplication architecture principals, found [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#/guide/application_architecture)

```
var view = this.getView('Contact'); //=> getView( name ) : Ext.Base
```

if a combobox is a item of a view that your controller is in charge off, then use [control](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) method also from Controller class.

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['Contact'],
    init: function() {

        //reference the view
        var view = this.getView('Contact');

        //reference the combobox change event
        this.control({
            'mywin combobox': {
                 change: this.onChangeContinent
            }
        });

    },
    onChangeContinent:function (field, value, options) {

        //here you can get combobox component and its value
        Ext.Msg.alert('Continent', value);
    }
});
```

### here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GRE7N/5/)

EDIT:

To reference one component from another, you can use Controller [ref](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-ref) method, like this:

```
refs: [{
    ref: 'combo',
    selector: 'mywin combobox'
}]
```

### here is a [fiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/GRE7N/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know, how do we get the selected value of the combobox in the controller on click of save button in this fiddle example..

Comment: Thanks Devor. I was using getComboView, instead of getCombo.

Comment: the getter method is generated using 'ref' value get + ref value (combo) = getCombo(). Cheers!