# ExtJs 4.2 - Proper way to communicate between view and controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I am looking for a proper way to implement communication between my views and their respective controllers.

- **Calling controller method from its view?**
- **Getting reference to its view inside controller?**

So for now, I am calling **controller's method in my view** like this:

```
Ext.define('SomeApp.view.SomeTab', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

alias: 'widget.someTab',

initComponent: function() {

    // Calling respective controller method to run the initializing sequence
    PfalzkomApp.app.getController('someTabController').initializeSomeTab();
    this.callParent();
}, ....
```

And to access my view inside my controller, I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464392/view-reference-in-controller-extjs-4)

```
Ext.define('SomeApp.controller.SomeTabController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    views: [
        'SomeTab'
    ],

    refs: [{
        ref: 'SomeTab',//xtype
    }],...
```

But I am only able to access my view after it is rendered which makes sense but I was wondering if there is a better solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, (although you are using ExtJS 4.2), you can follow the Extjs architecture of the newest versions (5+,6+) which is that each view has its particular controller (or viewcontroller) associated. It's better than having a controller that listens events of multiple views.

In your case the controller could be:

```
Ext.define('SomeApp.controller.SomeTabController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
```

....

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'someTab': {
             beforerender: this.loadView//use the event you want
         } 
    })
},

...
loadView: function(view){
    //your code
}
```

The `beforerender` method allows you to access the view before its rendered.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-beforerender

So,

**- Calling controller method from its view?** 
     Call the controller functions from the view can be donde with the property `listeners` and listen the event you want.

**- Getting reference to its view inside controller?**
In this case, if you register an event of a component to call a function on your controller, usually `this` should be your view (`someTab`). Also you can listen events of the components in your view with selectors.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am doing some important stuff in  initComponent http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-method-initComponent of my view.
So can you tell me how I can put my implementation of initComponent in the Controller?

Comment: I dont' understand what you are asking. What are you doing in the initComponent?

Comment: In my given code of view, you can see that inside initComponent method I am calling some method of a particular controller. 
Now my question is: 
If there is any other way to call this views controller's method?
Or
How can I move this initComponent definition from view to its controller?

Comment: Ah ok! In my answer you can see the function that is called when the `beforerender` event fires in the view, so call your function there: `beforerender: this.initializeSomeTab` and then implement that function in the controller.

Comment: It helped. 
Although I had to made some extra changes to solve my issue. 
I am still looking for way that how I can access the controller inside initComponent. I'll wait a little before I accept so may be I get some more responses. 
Thank your for your time.